# How to get correct launcher icon for google-earth?

Tags: google-chrome, icons, .desktop

How can I get correct icon for Google Earth in the launcher?

First I downloaded `google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb` from 
https://www.google.com/earth/download/ge/agree.html

Then I ran:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

When I now start Google Earth from the terminal:

```
google-earth &
```

and I get this incorrect icon in the launcher:

[image]

I checked that the desktop file at 
`/usr/share/applications/google-earth.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Google Earth
GenericName=3D planet viewer
Comment=Explore, search and discover the planet
Exec=/opt/google/earth/free/google-earth %f
Terminal=false
MultipleArgs=false
Icon=google-earth
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network
MimeType=application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml;application/vnd.google-earth.kmz;application/earthviewer;application/keyhole
```

and it looks ok. Note that the `Exec` value in the desktop file `/opt/google/earth/free/google-earth` is a correct symbolic link to the `google-earth` command.

Also, the icon at `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/google-earth.png`

[image]

looks ok.
How can I display this icon in the launcher?

Answer (score 2):

Update your file to :

```
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/google-earth.png
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. Do I have to restart the computer after making the change?